# Why "Replication cannot proceed because cannot maintain uniform access control list on replicas. Failed with XXXX server" message?

Tags: lotus-notes

A local relica was made by the "New Replica..." option in the client.
The Domino server is Release 8.5.2 FP!.
The Notes client is 8.5.2FP2

When running the replication on the client, I saw the replicator ran for a while and then stopped with a message "Replication cannot proceed because cannot maintain uniform access control list on replicas. Failed with XXXX server" in the replication entry.

What does this really mean? and Why?
Since the local replica was made by the "New REplica..." option, shalln't the ACL be the same active?

And how can I correct this? or do I have to recreate the local replica again?

Answer (score 0):

The ACL is the list of access users/groups that can get into the database. For security purposes you can set an option called "Enforce consistent ACL across all replicas".

If one of the replicas has a change in the ACL and it is inconsistent with the others, then it will not allow you to replicate. For example if a user was to create a local replica, was able to modify the ACL to give themselves more access and then attempted to replicate. You would get the error in this instance.

If it's a new replica, make sure enforce consistent ACL is on.

Otherwise, switch off "Enforce consistent ACL" on the local and server database and replicate, then switch it back on.

The option is at:  "File->Application->Access control list" menu, then select Advanced. The checkbox is there.